# How to change as read state when tableview did end displaying cell?

Tags: ios, iphone, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I try to create an application that aggregate feeds.

I want to change the feed state when table view did end displaying cell.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndDisplayingCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    Feed* feed = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if ([feed.read boolValue] == YES) return ;
    feed.read = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
    [Feed save];
}
```

I use NSFetchedResultsController and when I change the feed state I use reloadRowsAtIndexPath.

```
- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
    {
        switch(type) {
            ...
            case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
                [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]
                                      withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
                break;
            ...
        }
    }

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

I scroll, `didEndDisplayingCell` is called with the good `indexPath` and when `tableView` end updates, it calls again `didEndDisplayingCell` with the next `indexPath`. After that I have a serious error from core data.

```
CoreData: error: Serious application error.  An exception was caught from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to -controllerDidChangeContent:.  *** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 3 beyond bounds [0 .. 2] with userInfo (null)
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

why you update `coreData` in `didEndDisplayingCell`?
by calling `[Feed save]` then your `tableview` will begin update again.and the `tableView` will call `didEndDisplayingCell` because you reload a that row you just update.

so put the code in `didEndDisplayingCell` method somewhere else.

Comment: I want to update the cell to change its state to read, but I want to do it when tableView did end displaying cell. You scroll and when cell is out of the screen it's update to read state.
Where can I put the code out of didEndDisplayingCell ?

Comment: I consider you are doing an app like Feedly,so the tableView cells may show the titles of the feed. so when people click the cell and you push an `view controller` to show the detail. if so , why don't you update read state when you show the detail and let NSFetchedResultsController handle other things when you back to this page.

Comment: I get your point and like you said I want to do an app like feedly. At this point, I would like to update my feeds when the user scroll. On feedly is a little bit different because feedly has pages not a table view. When you scroll to the next page feedly update automatically feeds to read state. I would like to update automatically my feeds when cell is out of screen.

Comment: ok, i think here is a way you can do within this situation. create another data model(array,map、set) to save the cell's indexPath in `didEndDisplayingCell` to mark these cell as read. and then configure cell's read state in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`when those cell show again.

Comment: Or ,delete those code for `NSFetchedResultsController` , use `NSManagedObjectContext` to fetch data from your data model , use the fetch result as your tableView's datasource.Then you can do `[Feed save];` in `didEndDisplayingCell` safely, since you don't need to update tableview via `NSFetchedResultsController`.